# How to draw a graph with several axes?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to draw a graph as you can see it on the picture below:

[image]

All I got was this one here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    xlabel=$p$,ylabel=$\pi_1$,
    domain=0:1,xmin=0,xmax=1,
    ymin=0,ymax=4.2,
    no marks,clip=false]
    \addplot[dashed] { -x+3} node[above,sloped,pos=0.2] {$\pi_1((p,1-p),T)$};
    \addplot[dashed] {3*x+1} node[above,sloped,pos=0.7] {$\pi_1((p,1-p),H)$};
    \addplot[red] {ifthenelse(x>0.5,-x+3,3*x+1)};
    \draw[dotted,red] (axis cs:0,5/2) node[left] {$\underline{v} = \frac{5}{2}$}
      -| (axis cs:0.5,0) node[below] {$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{2}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

There are still things missing to make it similar to the graph I wish like to have. E.g. I do not have a label for the right axis. And there are too no arrows at the end of both axis. In addition the label is not where I want to have it. Also I was not able to put `p=0` resp. `p=1` where it has to be. I really wish to make it similar looking, but I do not really know how. These are my first steps in LaTeX. I hope someone may help me to solve these problems. Thank you in advance!!! (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Addendum:**
Finally I to unravel a puzzle with `xtick`, so the `extra x ticks`, which  was used in the first (now obsolete and erased) solution, is not necessary anymore and code is now more straightforward:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,prewiev]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=8cm, compat=1.13}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{% <-- common presets for both axes
            ylabel=$\pi_1$,
            domain=0:1,xmin=0,xmax=1,
            ymin=0,ymax=4.3,
            enlargelimits=false,
            clip=false
                }
  \begin{axis}[
axis y line=left,                   % <-- left y axis
ylabel style={at={(0,1)},rotate=-90,anchor=east},% <--
axis x line=bottom,                 % <--
x axis line style={-},              % <--
xlabel=$p$,
xtick={0, 0.25, 0.75, 1},           % <--
xticklabels={$p=0$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $p=1$},% <--
                ]
    \addplot[dashed] { -x+3} node[above,sloped,pos=0.2] {$\pi_1((p,1-p),T)$};
    \addplot[dashed] {3*x+1} node[above,sloped,pos=0.7] {$\pi_1((p,1-p),H)$};
    \addplot[red] {ifthenelse(x>0.5,-x+3,3*x+1)};
    \draw[dotted,red] (0,5/2) node[left] {$\underline{v} = \frac{5}{2}$}
      -| (0.5,0) node[below] {$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{2}$};
  \end{axis}
%
  \begin{axis}[
axis y line=right,                  % <-- right y axis
ylabel style={at={(1,1)},rotate=-90,anchor=west},% <--
axis x line=none,                   % <--
            ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above code are added things in comparison to MWE in question designated by `% <--`. Result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! Exactly what I was looking for : )

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes when you want lots of flexibility and extra details in a graph it's worth taking the trouble to draw it "from scratch" in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  Here I've wrapped it up in `luamplib` so you need to process this with `lualatex` (or adapt it for plain MP).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  % units - horizontal and vertical
  u = 10cm;
  v = 1.2cm;

  path xx, yy, yyy;
  xx = origin -- right scaled u;
  yy = origin -- up    scaled 4.4v;
  yyy = yy shifted (1u,0);

  z1 = (0,1v);  z2 = (1u,2v);
  z3 = (0,3v);  z4 = (1u,4v);
  z5 = (1/2u,5/2v);

  draw z1 -- z5 -- z2 withcolor red;
  draw (0,y5) -- z5 -- (x5,0) dashed withdots scaled 1/2 withcolor red; 

  path line[];
  line1 = z1--z4;
  line2 = z3--z2;
  draw line1 dashed evenly;
  draw line2 dashed evenly;

  draw textext("$\pi_1\bigl((p, 1-p),H\bigr)$")
       rotated angle direction 5/8 of line1
       shifted point 5/8 of line1
       shifted 6 up;

  draw textext("$\pi_1\bigl((p, 1-p),T\bigr)$")
       rotated angle direction 1/8 of line2
       shifted point 1/8 of line2
       shifted 6 up;

  for i=1 upto 4:
     draw (origin -- 3 left)  shifted (0,i*v);
     draw (origin -- 3 right) shifted (u,i*v);
     label.lft(decimal i, (0-3,i*v));
     label.rt (decimal i, (u+3,i*v));
  endfor

  for i=1 upto 3:
     draw (origin -- 3 down) shifted (i/4*u,0);
  endfor

  label.bot("$p=0$",     (   0,-5));
  label.bot("$p=1$",     (  1u,-5));
  label.bot("$\frac14$", (1/4u,-3));
  label.bot("$\frac34$", (3/4u,-3));

  label.bot("$\hat{p}=\frac12$",(1/2u,-3)) withcolor red;
  label.lft("$v=\frac52$",      (-3,5/2v)) withcolor red; 

  draw xx;
  drawarrow yy; label.top("$\pi_1$", point 1 of yy);
  drawarrow yyy;label.top("$\pi_1$", point 1 of yyy);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```