# How to plot a function with labels and a hatched area?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have now spend quite the whole afternoon to draw a function as you can see it on this picture here:

[image]

I thought it would not be to difficult. But I was wrong. I already asked google for help and all I know is, I have to use `tikz`. It is shamefull what I was able to get by now:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,5.5) node[right] {$u_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am so sorry for that, but I do not have any idea. Is there someone how me help me? Grateful for any response!!

PS: The functions are described by 2*x-1 resp. -2*x+1

Comment: this looks a lot like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317371/89976, with the addition of some `fillbetween`. An example of that would be http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245958/how-to-label-areas-in-pgfplots-fillbetween-library

Comment: @RunarTrollet,  slightly different, no second y-axis and xtick, but added shaded area :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ignasi suggest, solution with `pgfplots` ... it is not so simple as pure TikZ  solution, however it is based on my answer on similar your question and preserve style of drawing (if this matters):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=8cm, compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every pin edge/.style={<-,draw=black}
                        ]
  \begin{axis}[
axis y line=left,                   % <-- left y axis
ylabel style={at={(0,1)},rotate=-90,anchor=south},
ylabel=$u_1$,
ytick={0, 1},
yticklabels={$-1$, $1$},
%
axis x line=bottom,                 % <--
xlabel style={at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
xlabel=$x$,
xtick={0, 1},           
xticklabels={$0$, $1$},
%
domain=0:1,
xmin=0,xmax=1.1,ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
clip=false
                ]
    \addplot[draw=none] {x}; % <-- dummy line, 
                             % instead it can be drawn some function 
                             % (this is not clear from question)
% 
\draw[very thick, draw=red, fill=red!30]
    (0,0) -- (0.5,0.5) -- coordinate[pin=above right:{$u(x,R)$}] (ur) (1,0);
\draw[very thick]
    (0,1) -- (0.5,0.5) -- coordinate[pin=below right:{$u(x,L)$}] (ul) (1,1);
%
\draw[dashed]   (0,1)  -| (1,0);
\draw[dashed,draw=red]
                (0,.50)  node[left]  {$V=0$}  -| (0.5,0)  node[below] {$\frac{1}{2}$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting image:

[image]

**Edit:** 
Instead to draw lines in `pgflots`, it can be used `addplot` macro for doing this:

```
    \begin{axis}[ .... ]
\addplot[very thick, draw=red, fill=red!30]
        coordinates {(0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1,0)};
\addplot[very thick, draw=black]
        coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,0.5)  (1,1)};
\node[pin=below right:{$u(x,L)$}] at (0.75,0.75) {};
\node[pin=above right:{$u(x,R)$}] at (0.75,0.25) {};
    %
\draw[dashed]   (0,1)  -| (1,0);
\draw[dashed,draw=red]
                    (0,.50)  node[left]  {$V=0$}  -| (0.5,0)  node[below] {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{axes}
```

If you have more `pgfplots` pictures in document, you can define common presets, which you then call in particular images. By this the code of images become significantly more concise (see my question about [pgfplotsset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317615/can-be-pgfplotsset-named))

Comment: now, you beat me for more than 20 min.

Comment: See edit of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with pure `TiKZ` (without `pgfplots`):

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (1.5,-1) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$u_1$};
\draw[dashed] (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\draw (0,1) node[left] {1} -- coordinate (aux) coordinate[near end](aux2) (1,-1) node[below] {1};

\draw (0,-1) node[left] {-1} node[below]{0} --coordinate[pos=0.7] (aux3) (1,1);
\filldraw[thick, red, opacity=.5] (0,-1)--(aux)--(1,-1)--cycle;
\draw[red, thick,dashed] (0,0) node[left] {$V=0$} -| (0.5,-1) node[below]{$\frac{1}{2}$};

\draw[<-] (aux2) --++(15:1cm) node[right]{$u(x,R)$};
\draw[<-] (aux3) --++(-15:1cm) node[right]{$u(x,L)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you bit me for 52 seconds ...

Comment: Nice! I'm usually the looser. You still can beat me with a `pgfplots` solution ;-)

Comment: maybe, I will see. but it is more complicated :-(.

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!! Looks great : ). Is there a way to get the same length for (-1 to 1) and (0 to 1)? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @hpz1719. In this case, add `x=2cm` in `tikzpicture` options and `x` units will be 2cm instead of 1cm which is by default. As you don't touch `y=...`, it will remain being 1cm.