# Can be \pgfplotsset named?

Tags: pgfplots

For example, that in a document I have a set of `pgfplots` images with two or three distinctive common subsets of `\pgfplotsset{...}`. Is it possible to write them in document preamble and in particular `pgfplopts` image just call it (to be consider only selected one)? Similarly as it is possible with `tikzset`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a style:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  Your name here/.style =
    {
      % Settings
    }
  }
```

The same is true for `\tikzset` or `\pgfkeys`: the mechanism is the same, it's only the 'root' for the keys that varies.

Comment: Ah, so simple :-). Unfortunately, this is not mentioned in pgflopts manual or at least I didn't find this.